# Creating xml file from ms sql database using xsd

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xsd

I need "programmatically" create single xml file based on xsd with data from database(for example this db contains 20 table). This database created from this xsd file. I using `DataSet.ReadXmlScheme` and then from this dataset create ms sql database. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DataTable` from the SQL Server Table and then use then use [DataTable.WriteXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx) to export data to XML file.

This Code will fill a `datatable` then write it to an **XML** string:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM  TableName";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
dt.WriteXml(ms, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
ms.Close();
return xml;
```

you can use different methods to fill the `datatable` if you want